# Can I replicate Remote Control feature in Windows Server 2012 somehow?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access

Is there any replacement for the Remote Control functionality that used to be in Windows Server 2008 R2 that was removed from Windows Server 2012?

Remote Control means the feature when you go to the Task manager, go to the users page,and right click on an User, on a Terminal Server (RDS) machine, you could assist users who are logged into another RDS/TS remote desktop session.

My question is does Windows Server 2012 contain another feature which can be used to accomplish the remote support goal?  Both users need to be able to see the same desktop.

(if not, I'll have to find a third party tool, and iirc, that would be off topic here, so I'm not asking about that. Obviously GoToMeeting would work here, but that's not what I mean.)

Comment: SCCM has that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warren,

This is back in Windows 2012 R2.  See here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283323.aspx

> In Windows Server 2012 R2, Session Shadowing enables you to
>   remotely monitor or control an active session of another user on a
>   Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server. The current
>   version includes integration with Server Manager and Remote Desktop
>   Connection (mstsc.exe).

So basically, time to upgrade again.